# Как добавить тайлы на карту с помощью django_leaflet?

Tags: django, leafletjs, tile

С помощью плагина [django-leaflet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-leaflet) я отображаю карту на форме. Для этого нужно установить плагин, добавить его в INSTALLED_APPS и добавить в settings переменную LEAFLET_CONFIG с тайлами. Тайлы я могу загрузить так:

```
'TILES': 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
```

Насколько понятно из документации, на этом серверная часть закончилась. Далее в html-файле нужно в `header` добавить `{% load leaflet_tags %}` и дополнить раздел *head* строками

```
{% leaflet_js %}
{% leaflet_css %}
```

а в *body* - строку

```
{% leaflet_map "map" callback='map_init' %}
```

и скрипт:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   function map_init (map, options){ 
       L.marker(47.79470655664555, 39.13330078125).addTo(map);
   }
</script>
```

И карта отображается. Но возникает две проблемы: если задавать тайл не в settings, а  в скрипте кодом 
`L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);`, как указано в документации, то тайлы не загружаются. И вторая проблема: даже если описывать тайлы в settings, при выводе карты на печать у меня вместо карты пустое окно Leaflet - без подложки.
[image: Так выглядит страничка вывода на печать]
Печатаю страницу кодом

```
<script> 'use strict';
    window.print();
</script>
```

в том же темплейте.

P.S. Вторую проблему решает setTimeOut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается, использовать в темплейте лифлетовский код

```
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
```

можно только если в settings.py в LEAFLET_CONFIG указаны пустые тайлы:

```
'TILES': [],
```